# why Jsoup can't connect with some URL?

Tags: java, http, jsoup

In my little app im using the framework "Jsoup" for download the html, but the problem is that my code don't work with some urls. This is my code:

```
    public  static void main(String[] args) {

    String html=null;

    //Descargamos el html
    String url = "http://www.opposingviews.com";
    Connection conn = Jsoup.connect(url);
    try {
        Response resp = conn.execute();
        if (resp.statusCode() != 200) {
            System.out.println("Error: "+resp.statusCode());
        }else{
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is downloading "+ url);
            //html = conn.get().html();
        }   
    }catch(IOException e) {
           System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
           System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"No puedo conectar con  "+ url);
           System.out.println("No se puede conectar");
    }
```

And dont work with some urls like:

```
http://www.topix.com
http://www.wittyfeed.com
http://www.wittyfeed.com...
```

But work with others like: `http://www.google.com, http://www.amazon.es`...

The error is

```
org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:590),
org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:540),
org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:227), 
Practica1.prueba.main(prueba.java:34)
```

What can be the problem for this behavior?

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing with these URLs?

Comment: please add your Error `stackTrace` @RandallDaniBarrientos

Comment: @VikrantKashyap the error is : [org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:590), org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:540), org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:227), Practica1.prueba.main(prueba.java:34)] .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, you need to print what exception you get when you try to connect to the URL

which is

```
http://www.topix.comorg.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403, URL=http://www.topix.com
```

So please add the User agent like below

```
Connection conn = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
```

made changes to your code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Connection.Response;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;


public class JsonExample {

    public  static void main(String[] args) {

        String html=null;

        //Descargamos el html
        String url = "http://www.topix.com";
        Connection conn = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
        try {
            Response resp = conn.execute();
            if (resp.statusCode() != 200) {
                System.out.println("Error: "+resp.statusCode());
            }else{
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is downloading "+ url);
                //html = conn.get().html();
            }   
        }catch(IOException e) {
             System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
             System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"No puedo conectar con  "+ url + e);
             System.out.println("No se puede conectar");
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks  @likeToCode  , its work! jus one question. I have a file with 5000 url for download(actually im using threads), using this userAgent, is sure that all wil be downloaded? or the jsoup.connect depend of UserAgent and url? Thanks

Comment: Using the user agent it should work with all the URL's. You can try it and reach out if any issues and accept my answer as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
Elements link = doc.select("a");
        System.out.println(link.size());
        int c=0;
        String[] prices = new String[link.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < link.size(); i++) {
            prices[i] = link.get(i).attr("href");
            if(prices[i].contains("https")){
                c++;
                String nurl = prices[i].replace("%2B","+");
                String surl = nurl.replace("%3D","=");
                String urll=prices[i];
                System.out.println(prices[i]);
                URLEncoder.encode(prices[i], "UTF-8");
                System.out.println(c+"\t"+surl);
//              Connection connection2 = Jsoup.connect(surl);
//              Response doc2=connection2.execute();
                Document doc3 = Jsoup.connect(surl).post();
                //Document doc3=Jsoup.connect(makeSearch).get();
                String blk=doc3.html();
```

Comment: Please explain your answer!

Answer (score 0):

For me changing the user agent to "Mozilla/5.0" alone fixed the issue.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
                            .timeout(30000)
                            .get();
```